# Policy based design in a real world open source project

Tags: c++, open-source, policy-based-design

Can anybody point me to an open source C++ project(preferably not a lib), where policy based design is extensively used?

Comment: Note: Policy is also called Strategy in Design Patterns. The two are used more or less interchangeably.

Comment: @MatthieuM. With the difference that PBD is compile time only.

Comment: @jotep: for Alexandrescu; but I have seen Strategy being employed for compile-time parametrization, and I would not bet than Policy was not employed for runtime polymorphism mechanisms...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, I'm only familiar with PBD via Templates and that  makes it pretty much compile-time only.

Comment: @jotep: Yes, of course, however note that a Dependency Injection which consists in injecting (possibly stateful) behavior inside an object may rely either on compile-time or runtime polymorphism. They are (usually) dubbed Policy-Based design and Strategy pattern respectively, but since they existed long before being named... the names do not necessarily stick.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Hm, very true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose that any C++ application using the STL containers (parameterized by an Allocator and, sometimes, a Comparator) extensively use Policy-Based design. It's been a corner stone of the STL even seen it saw the light at SGI.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I just try to come up with a good example to go through with students.

Comment: @Shamdor: well, I think that the `Comparator` example of `std::set` and `std::map` is a rather good example. It's pervasive and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious one by Alexandrescu: [Loki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loki-lib/)

It's being actively developed.

Comment: Well, this is a lib. I was thinking more about apps. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Libraries are harder to design than your standard application, which use them. If you ask me, policy based design makes sense only in API design. And remember Joshua Bloch, "If you program, you are an API designer."

Answer (score 1):

any project that is using boost :-) http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#policy

if you mean initiating policy-based objects, than it would be a lot of projects that use boost. For example, http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/Boost/BGL/DijkstraDirected
or you can look at big projects on github https://github.com/search?q=%23include+%3Cboost%2Fgraph%2Fgraph_traits.hpp%3E&type=Code&ref=searchresults

if you mean defining policy-based object, than most of the use cases would be libraries. The reason for that is that if somethings needs a lot of customization and can be generalized, it becomes a library (even if for internal use). If you just writing a straightforward program that doesn't need customization of objects and poly-morphism, than it wouldn't use much of policy-based design.
for those, you can also search on github, trying out some common policy-based syntaxes.

In my scientific work, I use boost's odeint library that relies on policies. When I code, i start with a specialized hamiltonian, than I generalize it with policies and it basically becomes a library that I use in many other projects.